# GRAILS SOAP CLIENT WSLITE PARAMETERS

Tags: web-services, grails, grails-plugin

I have a SOAP client with Wslite plugin that works fine, but the parameters are not sent in the best way.

```
def calcClient(Integer n1, Integer n2) throws Exception {
    def response
    try {
        soapClient.serviceURL = "http://localhost:8080/SISAP/services/sendMail?wsdl"

        response = soapClient.send() {
            soapNamespacePrefix "soap"
            envelopeAttributes "xmlns:util":"http://util.unime.edu.br/"
            body {
                calc{
                    //is not the best way           
                    mkp.yieldUnescaped "<util:number1>$n1</util:number1>"
                    mkp.yieldUnescaped "<util:number2>$n2</util:number2>"
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        log.error(exception.message)
        throw exception
    }

    println response.body.calculaResponse.return
    return
}
```

It's working fine, but when I try:

```
calc{
   number1(n1)
   number2(n2)
}
```

Or

```
calc{
   "util:number1($n1)"
   "util:number2($n2)"
}
```

Or

```
calc{
   "{util}number1($n1)"
   "{util}number2($n2)"
}
```

The web service throws exception with no parameters sent.

What  am I doing wrong? :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to type

```
 mkp.yieldUnescaped.number1('xmlns':'util',n1)
 mkp.yieldUnescaped.number2('xmlns':'util',n2)
```

to make this work.